# Limitations on "plunder" ability?

Tags: charlotte

Charlotte is a very interesting show featuring people with powerful abilities, but all of them have limitations. For example, the "time jump" ability makes the user's vision fade, and the "high speed" ability causes the user to move at an uncontrollable but very fast speed.
The "plunder" ability is introduced late in the game, and it

> allows the user to steal other ability-wielder's abilities.

However, as far as I can remember, there was never a limitation for this ability explicitly declared. Did I miss something? Are there no limitations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's two side effects. The first is immediately noticeable: he cannot control his own body when he is controlling someone else's. This results in his body slumping over awkwardly.

The second effect is less obvious.  The more he uses his ability, the more memories he loses. This is likely due to the sheer amount of the brain all of these abilities are taking up.

This second effect can be seen gradually increasing as he forgets his mission, his friends, and eventually everything in the last episode.

It seems reasonable that he gets two negative side-effects like this since his ability lets him control people's bodies and steal abilities.

Answer (score 9):

The direct repercussion of using the plunder ability is that the user is knocked out for 5 seconds.

However, if the ability is used many times, it indirectly causes the user to lose their memory. As mentioned on the [Wikia article on Yū Otosaka](http://charlotte-anime.wikia.com/wiki/Y%C5%AB_Otosaka):

> Over the course of his journey, Yū's abilities, as well as the constant danger he faces, begin to take their toll on him. He shows signs of PTSD and is unable to sleep, and if he does sleep he sleepwalks and attacks enemy ability users as well as innocent civilians. Gaps in his memory start to form, and he finds himself unable to remember either his past or his goal. He isn't even able to remember Nao, but he is able to remember their promise.

It is also explicitly mentioned there as:

> Although "Plunder" has a side effect. The more people he loots abilities from, the more memories he loses.